# Observable dependency

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

Consider I have an observable which is depend on one state variable of the system much more than other variables. The dependency can be linear or nonlinear (and there is no linear correlation). Is there any way to find that the observable is carrying information from one of the states more than the others. For example, in the following figures, `f` depends on `x` and seems weak or non-dependent on `y`.
Is there any way to figure it out from data itself?

f vs x (dependency can be observed visually):
[image]

f vs y seems scattered:
[image]

Comment: You might want to consider moving this question to CrossValidated (stats.SE).

Comment: The question is too old to be migrated. (There's a 60-day limit on the age of questions for migrations.) You can re-ask it on [stats.se] yourself, however.